# Python. Print mac address out of 6 byte string

Tags: python, printing, tcp

I have mac address in 6 byte string. How would you print it in "human" readable format?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps to make it more readable you could actually look up the manufacturer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import struct
"%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x" % struct.unpack("BBBBBB",your_variable_with_mac)
```

Comment: You should probably use `%02x` instead of `%x`. Otherwise, the preceding *0* is missing for bytes below *16*.

Answer (score 12):

There's no need to use `struct`:

```
def prettify(mac_string):
    return ':'.join('%02x' % ord(b) for b in mac_string)
```

Although if `mac_string` is a `bytearray` (or `bytes` in Python 3), which is a more natural choice than a string given the nature of the data, then you also won't need the `ord` function.

Example usage:

```
>>> prettify(b'5e\x21\x00r3')
'35:65:21:00:72:33'
```

Comment: I find `b.encode('hex')` slightly more readable than `'%02x' % ord(b)`, but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 9):

In *Python 3.8* and above, you can just use [`bytes.hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex).

```
b'\x85n:\xfaGk'.hex(":") // -> '85:6e:3a:fa:47:6b'
```

Comment: Makes a handy mac address formatter: `decimal_mac.to_bytes(6, "big").hex(":")`

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
for b in addr:
    print("%02x:" % (b))
```

Where addr is your byte array.

Answer (score 0):

s=b'\x04NZ\xdf\x7f\xab'

1)
import struct
ssid_2 = "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x" % struct.unpack("BBBBBB", s)

or

2)
':'.join(f'{x:02x}' for x in s)

but 1) is way faster than 2)

Answer (score -3):

Is the usual hex format not human-readable enough? ([see this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/510399-byte-to-hex-and-hex-to-byte-string-conversion/) for a way to convert a byte to hex)

```
de:ad:be:ef:ca:fe
```

Incidentally, this is the way MAC addresses are displayed in most software (just Windows uses dashes instead of colons).