# Formatting a MAC address string with :'s

Tags: python-2.7

Python 2.7

I have a string

> 0091EA-EA0A1D

which I would like to format in a print statement to output like this

> 00:91:EA:EA:0A:1D

Yes, I could use the brute force method to take the string apart and put it back together with the desired format.  However, I'm trying to find out if there is a simpler/better way to do this in Python2.7?

Thanks....RDK

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a library function especially for Ethernet MACs. I would suggest:

```
s = '0091EA-EA0A1D'.replace('-', '')
':'.join('%02X' % ord(c) for c in s.decode('hex'))
```

Or, very similar, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11006780/235548).

Comment: Worked like a champ. Where do you folks learn all of this stuff.  I tried Googling and reading a Python book on formatting, but it did not help... Thanks....RDK