# MAC format from CSV file

Tags: python

Based on the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006702/elegant-format-for-a-mac-address-in-python-3-2):

I can easily format a single MAC. But I'm having an issue trying to do multiple from a csv file. When I run the file, it converts them but the script will convert each one like 6 times. If I add "return" then it only converts the first one 6 times.

```
def readfile_csv():
    with open('ap_macs.csv', 'r',encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for lines in csv_reader:
            data = (lines[0])
            for i in range(0,12,2):
                 format_mac = ':'.join(data[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, 12, 2))
                 print(format_mac.swapcase())
```

Ideally, I'd love to be able to do this with Pandas and Excel but the indexing is killing me. Appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
    ap_macs
A1B2C3D4E5F6
A1B2C3D4E5F7
A1B2C3D4E5F8
A1B2C3D4E5F9
a1b2c3d4e5f6
a1b2c3d4e5f7
a1b2c3d4e5f8
a1b2c3d4e5f9
```

Comment: Indentation matters in python. Since [code formatting](/help/format) on Stack Overflow uses indent, you need to check that the code in your question has the same indentation as the code in your IDE. I fixed the indentation of your code by adding code fences, but please check that this is accurate and take care to avoid this in future posts.

Comment: Also, please provide a [mre] that we can use to reproduce your issue. We do not have access to your `ap_macs.csv`, so please provide a snippet of that file _as formatted text_ as a part of your question

Comment: It looks like your CSV file has multiple columns containing MAC addresses without colons, and you want to add colons to all the columns, but it's hard to know for sure from your question. A snippet of the CSV, in addition to the expected vs. actual output would help clarify.

Comment: Thakn you @PranavHosangadi. I guess copy/paste messed up the indentation. Correct I want to add colons to all MACs. Editing the original post with the csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pandas for this. Note that pandas is overkill if all you're using it for is to read the csv.

```
df = pd.read_csv('ap_macs.csv')

# Slice the mac addresses into chunks
# This list will contain one `pd.Series` each for the second through last chunks
chunks = [df["ap_macs"].str[i:i+2] for i in range(2, 12, 2)]

# Then concatenate all the chunks, with a separator, to the first chunk
df["MAC"] = df['ap_macs'].str[0:2].str.cat(chunks, ":")
```

which gives:

```
        ap_macs                MAC
0  A1B2C3D4E5F6  A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6
1  A1B2C3D4E5F7  A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F7
2  A1B2C3D4E5F8  A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F8
3  A1B2C3D4E5F9  A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F9
4  a1b2c3d4e5f6  a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6
5  a1b2c3d4e5f7  a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f7
6  a1b2c3d4e5f8  a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f8
7  a1b2c3d4e5f9  a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f9
```

Of course, you can overwrite the `ap_macs` column if you want, but I created a new column for this demonstration.

---

If you want to use your `csv.reader` approach, you need to create your string first, and then print it.

```
def readfile_csv():
    # csv_data = []
    with open('ap_macs.csv', 'r',encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            data = row[0]
            for i in range(0,12,2):
                 format_mac = ':'.join(data[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, 12, 2)).swapcase()
            print(format_mac)
            # csv_data.append(format_mac)         
    # return csv_data
```

which will print:

```
a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6
a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f7
a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f8
a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f9
A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6
A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F7
A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F8
A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F9
```

Note that printing is not the same as returning data, and if you actually want to use this data outside the function, you'll have to return it (uncomment the commented lines)

Comment: Thank you, so for the first one using Pandas, I must be doing something wrong because that still isn't working for me. Second one works, looks like I had my last print statement in the wrong spot. Thank you for your help. I will play around with the first one and see if I can figure that out myself. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Using Pandas to *only* read CSV is ridiculous and should be a felony =)

Comment: I understand that, but I'm trying to learn this a little too. And that seems like an easy way to go as step 1. I do need to eventually use excel and currently working on that. It is complicated though.

Comment: @KlasŠ. I agree, I should have included that warning in the answer. I only included a pandas approach because OP said they'd like to use Pandas.

Comment: @Ali if you share the error message here I can try to help you figure it out

Comment: Thank you @PranavHosangadi for all your help. I got this working with the csv, I am working next on using pandas to read and excel file, but I'll create a separate post for it.